# Which countries in Europe have teaching positions that do not require doing research?

Tags: teaching, career-path, professorship, early-career

The question is regarding Computer Science field. I wish to know which countries have such teaching positions that do not require doing active research.

Also, what are these positions called?

And, is a PhD required for these positions or Master's is sufficient?

Comment: This question seems out of scope here (shopping question).
But to help you a little bit -- if 1 paper / 2-3 years is an acceptable publishing rate for you, then an undergraduate Lecturer position in the UK may be suitable for you.

Comment: @101010111100 The question mentions not doing active research. Positions in the UK described as "Lecturer" are really equivalent to "Assistant Professor" and, in Mathematics, would **almost always** require one to be doing active research. Teaching-only positions would be advertised and described as something like "full-time Teaching Fellowships" or similar

Comment: @YemonChoi In general, yes. But there are at least 2 people in my faculty, one Senior Lecturer and one Lecturer, who have pretty spotty publication record. E.g. one of them has one publication in 2016, one in 2014, one in 2010, etc. The other one has one publication in 2015, one in 2012, one in 2010, etc. Both of them focus mostly on teaching undergrads. If it matters, one of them works in Nano Engineering, the other one in Mathematical Foundations.

Comment: @101010111100 My guess is that these people have been working at that university for more than 10-15years already, and may have benefited from easier times in UK academia. It is possible, once appointed, *if you are lucky*, to shift to a role where you publish less and less; but I think anyone applying for a Lectureship on the basis that they can start off not being research active is unlikely to make the shortlist

Comment: Such positions exist, but you will have to be able to teach in the language of the country. Universities will accept a researcher to only give advanced lectures in English, but someone has to teach the basic levels, and it will be that guy.Chances of getting such a positon without a doctorate are negligible. And you don't find this at the regular universities but at smaller institutions more aimed at professional education, not academia.

Answer (score 4):

Germany has "Akademischer Rat", which can be permanent or nonpermanent. Depending on the faculty, it can contain various combinations of research, teaching and administration -- permanent "Akademischer Rat" positions in the sciences often consist purely of teaching and administration, but they are rare these days.

Furthermore, the German "Fachhochschule" or "Hochschule" offers professorships which consist mainly of teaching, but they require at least 3 years of working experience in industry.

Answer (score 1):

For higher education teaching positions in the UK, the role is called "**teaching fellow**", very often part-time and short-term.

PhD expected as there are so many candidates longing for any sort of position on the job market.

This type of position usually expects a track record of University teaching at undergraduate and postgraduate level, and probably expects too more often than not a track record of published research, following the long-standing cliche - true or false is beyond the point: good researchers make good teachers.

The worst part of the deal is probably the part-time aspect, as teaching can easily take a full-time commitment, but higher education institutions keep careful tracking of how full-time staff split their time between admin, research and teaching activities. This in turn gets used to draw in casual teaching staff.

Answer (score 0):

In France, there are several positions in universities were you are not expected to do research even if you have a PhD. This include Research Engineer (but dedicated to tutorials ou courses teaching), and PRAG position. You can even be associate Professor choose to dedicate your time to teaching in accordance with your colleagues who will do more research and less teaching. There are formal contract to authorize that.

Comment: can you provide some links or details? Are these public positions?

Comment: I am afraid it is hard to find english description in public websites but if you target french universities one by one like [upmc](htt://upmc.fr) it is possible to find descriptions. French position in educations are public on [gouv.fr](https://www.galaxie.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/ensup/cand_recrutement.htm) and you can have an exemple in [umpc](http://www.upmc.fr/fr/universite/recrutements_et_concours/enseignants_chercheurs.html) through the french website.

Comment: I am afraid it is hard to find english description in public websites but if you target french universities one by one like [upmc](htt://upmc.fr) it is possible to find descriptions. French position in educations are public on [gouv.fr](https://www.galaxie.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/ensup/cand_recrutement.htm) and you can have an exemple in [umpc](http://www.upmc.fr/fr/universite/recrutements_et_concours/enseignants_chercheurs.html) through the french website.

Comment: Not a problem I speak French and I would not expect to apply to a job in a country where I don't have some knowledge of the language. Thanks for the info.